# 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443)

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-automl

I am getting an error when trying to run `get_prediction` from my AutoML custom model multiple times within my program. How Can I fix this?

```py
def get_prediction(self,tweet,full_tweet):
    content = 'walgreens sucks'
    prediction_client = automl_v1beta1.PredictionServiceClient()
    name = 'projects/{}/locations/us-central1/models/{}'.format(project_id, model_id)
    payload = {'text_snippet': {'content': content, 'mime_type': 'text/plain' }}
    params = {}
    request = prediction_client.predict(name, payload, params)  
    return request
```

Here is the error :

> google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))

Answer (score 3):

Yes I also faced the same problem

For my case, I make a silly mistake, I am initiating the client inside a function and the function is called from a loop. That means it initiates client on each call. Here is the code:

```
from google.cloud import translate

import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="locaions of credential"

def sample_translate_text(text):
 """Translating Text."""

 try:
     project_id="project id"
     client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

     parent = client.location_path(project_id, "global")

     response = client.translate_text(
         parent=parent,
         contents=[text],
         mime_type="text/plain", 

         target_language_code="en-US",
     )

     for translation in response.translations:
         return translation.translated_text
 #      
 except Exception  as e:
     print(str(e))
     return None
```

```
  for i in range(0, 1000):
      sample_translate_text("আমার মাথা ব্যাথা")
```

output:

```
most frequently I got this error 

503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known',))
```

Then initiate the client Outside the function check my below code:

```
from google.cloud import translate

import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="location of credential"
project_id="project id"
client = translate.TranslationServiceClient()

parent = client.location_path(project_id, "global")
def sample_translate_text(text):
    """Translating Text."""

    try:
        response = client.translate_text(
            parent=parent,
            contents=[text],
            mime_type="text/plain", 

            target_language_code="en-US",
        )

        for translation in response.translations:
            return translation.translated_text
    #      
    except Exception  as e:
        print(str(e))
        return None
```

```
   for i in range(0, 1000):
       sample_translate_text("আমার মাথা ব্যাথা")
```

This case I got success

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact context that this function is in, but what is probably happening is that you initiate the client very often, in a loop for example (every time you call the function). The solution is to make the client global or pass it as an argument to the function. This should work:

```
prediction_client = automl_v1beta1.PredictionServiceClient()

def get_prediction(self,tweet,full_tweet):
    content = 'walgreens sucks'
    name = 'projects/{}/locations/us-central1/models/{}'.format(project_id, model_id)
    payload = {'text_snippet': {'content': content, 'mime_type': 'text/plain' }}
    params = {}
    request = prediction_client.predict(name, payload, params)  
    return request
```